# tf.divide() does not support gradient for input with int type

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow-1.4.1 on my Ubuntu14.04, and I want to create my custom loss function called `Dice Loss` in the following way:

```
>>> # true_labels and pred_labels are in type int64
>>> a = tf.square(true_labels)
>>> b = tf.square(pred_labels)
>>> upper = tf.multiply(true_labels, pred_labels)
>>> lower = tf.add(a, b, upper)
>>> iou = tf.divide(upper, lower)
>>> loss = tf.subtract(tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float64), iou)
```

However, I found that `tf.divide()` does not supply gradient when input type is int32 or int64. And I haved checked this in a more general situation below:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> a = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int64)
>>> b = tf.constant(2, dtype=tf.int64)
>>> c = tf.divide(a, b)
>>> g = tf.gradients(c, a)
>>> print(g)
```

And it turns out to be:

```
>>> [None]
```

When I change the `dtype` of `a` from `int64` to `float32`, it can return the right result `[<tf.Tensor 'gradients/truediv_grad/Reshape:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]`

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `upper` and `lower` to tf.float32 types using `tf.cast`. So the divide line could be:

```
upper = tf.cast(upper, tf.float32)
lower = tf.cast(lower, tf.float32)
iou = tf.divide(upper, lower)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, tf.cast() does not supply gradient either.

Comment: Ah you're right, I've updated the answer (this version works for me). Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: It dose help in simple situation, but still fails in my case, though. Considering the following situation:`a: int64, b: int64, c = a + b; d = a * b, c = tf.cast(c, tf.float32); d = tf.cast(d, tf.float32); e = tf.divide(c, d); g = tf.gradients(e, a)`. and it still turns out to be `[None]`.